# ErrorException: Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: php, redirect, symfony

I am having trouble redirecting after a certain function that sends emails!
My function is:

```
public function emailAction($emails, $url)
{

    foreach($emails as $email)
    {
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Updates in Symfony Blog')
            ->setFrom(array('blog@symfonyblog.com' => 'Symfony Blog'))
            ->setTo($email["email"])
            ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'NEWSBlogBundle:Default:email.txt.twig',
                array('url' => $url)
            )
        )
        ;
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->newpostAction());
    //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('NEWSBlogBundle_homepage'));

}
```

It sends the emails OK, but then when redirecting, gives the error:

> ErrorException: Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3899
>
> 1. in C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3899
> 2. at ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected', 'C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php', '3899', array('this' => object(RedirectResponse), 'name' => 'Location', 'values' => array('/app_dev.php/blog', object(ResponseHeaderBag), '     Redirecting to /app_dev.php/blog   Redirecting to /app_dev.php/blog.  ', '1.0', '302', 'Found', null), 'value' => object(ResponseHeaderBag)))
> 3. at header('Location: Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 11:56:17 GMT Location: /app_dev.php/blog ', false) in C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3899
> 4. at Response->sendHeaders() in C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3914
> 5. at Response->send() in C:\path\to\webroot\Symfony\web\app_dev.php line 27

while I haven't changed anything about any "headers" (and don't really know what it is about!). My app_dev.php is:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I tried two different ways of redirecting both (through routing and directly calling the controller) of which give the same error, whilst the pages load if I jusr type in their url!

I have NO idea what this error is and how I should fix it!

Comment: maybe you have an output of a whitespace somewhere in your files

Comment: What is the return valeu of `$this->newpostAction()`

Comment: @Pazi
It's a controller function which loads a page.

Comment: I didn't figure out what the problem was but I removed the "function" and added its functionallity to the controller that was calling it, and my problem was solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be detail, your problem was the return value of `$this->newpostAction()`. Usally it's a `Response` object. But a redirect expects an uri/route, which can be sent to the client via the `Location` header. A redirect is always a client side turn around. But you can use `->forward('AcmeBundle:Demo:index')` to forward internally to another controller action. In this case the URL on the client is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

You trigger a sanity check of Symfony. When sending headers with `header()`, theoretically you could send plenty of headers with one function call. Symfony prevents you from accidentally doing it when passing something with a newline character as the target URL.

Comment: How are headers sent?
If i try
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('NEWSBlogBundle_homepage'));
from a different controller it works fine!

Comment: I didn't figure out what the problem was but I removed the "function" and added its functionallity to the controller that was calling it, and my problem was solved!