# Laravel 5.3 LoginController - Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have a problem when changing the default `LoginController` redirect after login, I'm getting an 
`ErrorException in Response.php line 339:
Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected`

I have already tried everything but it just does not work, the code is:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (\Auth::check()) {
       $user_id = \Auth::id();
       $usuario = users::where('id','=',$user_id)->first();
       if($usuario->hasRole('copy')){
           return redirect('/copy/dashboardCopy');
        }
    } 
}

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
}
```

According to Laravel documentation, the method has higher priority than the attribute, so I assume it's okay to leave the class attribute as it is.

And also, I have already checked, and the code is actually reaching the last condition.

Comment: related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954971/cant-redirect-with-lot-of-variable-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-h or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699303/errorexception-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-l

Comment: Umm yes but, I can't see in which part it's redirecting twice.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez I can't see the part that's redirecting at all in this question. All I see is a function that *if* called, and *if* its result is returned as a response will cause a redirect. Might be worth checking **where** that response is generated and what is included in it.

Comment: @apokryfos 
The redirecting part is `return redirect('/copy/dashboardCopy');`, and as I mentioned, the code reaches that part...
Laravel doesn't say anything about checking elsewhere, [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authentication-quickstart], it just says to add the method and do the logic you want to.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The method redirectTo should return an url path, not the Redirect response.

```
...
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('copy')){
        return '/copy/dashboardCopy';
    }       
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was using `return redirect()->route('series');` instead of `return route('series');`

Comment: Managed to copy and paste the redirect from RedirectIfAuthenticated into the Controllers, you've just saved my sanity

Answer (score 5):

I have just solved it replacing the original code, with

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo;

protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('copy')){
        $this->redirectTo = '/copy/dashboardCopy';
        return $this->redirectTo;
    }       
}

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public $redirectTo = '/lender/home';

protected function redirectTo()
{
    if(\Auth::guard('lender')->check()){
      $this->redirectTo = '/lender/home';
      return $this->redirectTo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Comment This Part in Authenticate.php Of app/Http/Middleware

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
         {
             if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
                return view('admin.auth.login');

             }
         }
```