# Laravel login error 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected laravel login'

Tags: php, authentication, header, laravel-5.3

I am making a multi-auth custom login for clients. The login/logout works fine the first time I login, but shows this error in the second attempt

> ErrorException in Response.php line 339:
>   Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected'

what may be the cause for this?

Comment: Some code may well be useful to us.  how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320403/getting-warning-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header-new-line-dete

Comment: If you use `redirect(...)` method inside the `redirectTo(...)` method of `Authenticate.php` Middleware, It throws that error. You need to create a `Named Route` and then call it using `route(...)` inside `redirectTo(...)` method instead of using `redirect(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

you should use

```
return route('admin.dashboard');
```

instead of

```
 return redirect('admin/dashboard');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing same issue. Watching closely, I noticed that the header that is being passed contains not just a newline char, but also html code. A code for a page just annoucing the redirection to the route I wanted it to redirect.

My login is redirectTo is

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->route((string)\Auth::user()->group->type);
}
```

Where already exists a named route for each group->type possible.

I've already tried just a return to the route path with no success or any different error message.

[UPDATE] I found a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011025/laravel-5-3-logincontroller-header-may-not-contain-more-than-a-single-header#42033518), changed my code to this and it worked:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    // return redirect()->route((string)\Auth::user()->group->type);
    return route(\Auth::user()->group->type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in LoginController.

```
public function redirectTo(){

   $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

   $role_manager = User::where('id', $user_id)->value('role');

   if($role_manager == 'manager'){

       return $this->redirectTo = 'dashboard';

   }
}
```